# CSS sprite animation start with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I would like to control (start) a css sprite animation with JQuery, but I don't find the solution. I will start the anim with a click event, so I placed a test button to the JSFiddle code.
How can I do it? Thanks for the answers!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#jqtest").click(function() {
    $("#jqtest").css({
      'background-color': 'green'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#aloadingframes {
  width: 190px;
  height: 240px;
  background: url('https://3wga6448744j404mpt11pbx4-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/monster.png');
  background-size: cover;
  animation: loadingsprite 1s steps(10) 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes loadingsprite {
  100% {
    background-position: -1900px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aloadingframes"></div>
<button id="jqtest">JQuery test</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/devinphp/7t0rcagy/1/

Comment: Make the animation a CSS class and have your button remove and add that class on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#jqtest").click(function() {
    $("#aloadingframes").addClass("anim");

    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#aloadingframes").removeClass("anim");
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
#aloadingframes {
  width: 190px;
  height: 240px;
  background: url('https://3wga6448744j404mpt11pbx4-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/monster.png');
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
}

.anim {
  animation: loadingsprite 1s steps(10) 1;
}

@keyframes loadingsprite {
  100% {
    background-position: -1900px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aloadingframes"></div><button id="jqtest">JQuery test</button>
```